# Need Comma After Enum to Properly Output Values to List

Tags: python, enums, type-conversion

I am trying to create a helper function that converts the values of an Enum to list.

It works if I do this:

```
from enum import Enum

class TestEnum(Enum):
  item1 = 'Def1',
  item2 = 'Def2',
  item3 = 'Def3',

@staticmethod
def createListFromEnum(enum):
  return [elem.value[0] for elem in enum]

print(createListFromEnum(TestEnum))
```

Which outputs:

```
['Def1','Def2','Def3']
```

But if I don't put the trailing comma after the last item, I get:

```
['Def1','Def2','D']
```

Because the final entry is not registered as a tuple for some reason. I have looked at the other responses for converting an enum to value list, but none of them seem to address this as a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the commas in the enum.

I think this is what you want:

```
from enum import Enum

class TestEnum(Enum):
    item1 = 'Def1'
    item2 = 'Def2'
    item3 = 'Def3'

def createListFromEnum(enum):
    return [elem.value for elem in enum]

print(createListFromEnum(TestEnum))
```

Output:

```
['Def1', 'Def2', 'Def3']
```

See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you address the first element in a `tuple`. In the second case you don't have a `tuple` and address the first character of a `string`.

Look at this simple example:

```
>>> print(('python',)[0])
python
>>> print('python'[0])
p
```